# How can I make a wolf tamed by an arbitrary player using command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In a map I'm making, I have a shop where players can buy rewards for collecting points (things like upgraded stats, items, etc.). One thing I'd like to have is a pet shop, where the player can buy a dog, cat, horse, or skeleton horse. When they buy one, it should become tamed by the player who bought it. There's a data tag on these mobs called OwnerUUID, which must be set to the owner's UUID to make this work...so how can I set it to a player's UUID when anyone could be playing the map, and any player could buy an animal? In other words, how do I calculate the player's UUID and set a data tag to it if their username/account is unknown? If there's no way to do this, how can I make an animal tamed another way with command blocks?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question - but instead of taming the wolf in the shop, you could summon a separate tamed wolf and give it to the player. That would likely be the easier option.

Comment: That'd be fine, but then how do I make the summoned wolf be tamed and owned by the player? I'm trying to give them a wolf that will teleport to them and which they can make sit or stand.

Comment: I'm uncertain of the syntax for that, I'm just saying that the command for that would be much simpler. If you give me some time I might be able to whip something up for you :)

Comment: I think your best bet is to summon a wild wolf and give the player some bones

Comment: @ModDL Yeah, that's what I'm currently doing. Giving the player infinite bones until the wolf is tamed, and locking them in the room with the wolf until then as well. It just seems very inefficient, seeing as how horses can be tamed with a simple tag (Tamed:1b), but everything else requires an OwnerUUID.

Comment: This is not possible AFAIK.

Comment: *Sigh* I was afraid of that. Oh, well, guess I'll stick with the "lock a player in the room with a bunch of bones until they tame the dog" method...

Comment: This is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why so many players say this isn't possible. In fact, it is simple!

Just enter this command into a command block:

```
/summon Wolf ~ ~1 ~ {Owner:Notch}
```

Of course, the name `Notch` could be replaced with the player's name that you wanted to have it tamed to. `@p` does *not* work! (The command will generate a tamed wolf one block above the command block, tamed to the person of your liking.)

Comment: As I mentioned in the original question, I have no way of knowing the player who will have this dog. It's a map I'd like to release to the public. That's why it can't be hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

Summon a willed wolf with a command block then have the same circuit that activated the first command block to activate another command block which will give the player some bones.

Sorry for not getting the exact answer you wanted, but this will still work because this way you don't need to know the players name and they still get their pet wolf.

example

```
command block one          command block two
/summon wolf ~ ~1 ~         /give @p bone 15
```